# функция ничего не возвращает

Tags: python, функции

Начал изучать python. Пишу мини-программу для объединения двух txt файлов в третий с переносом строки. Функция ничего не возвращает (Process finished with exit code 0). Помогите исправить

```py
import fileinput
    
def tss_packer(cert, key):
    cert = cert.name, cert.PATH
    cert.name = input('Введите имя файла сертификата: \n')
    cert.PATH = 
    'C:\\Users\\Asus\\PycharmProjects\\tss_packer\\cert.txt'
    
    key = key.name, key.PATH
    key.name = input('Введите имя ключа: \n')
    key.PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\PycharmProjects\\tss_packer\\key.txt'
    
    result = cert.PATH, key.PATH
    with open(cert.name+'_'+key.name + 'txt', 'w') as file:
        input_lines = fileinput.input(result)
        file.writelines(input_lines)

tss_packer(cert, key, result)
```

Comment: а где вы эту функцию вызываете? и где вы ей говорите то-либо возвращать? я не нашел вот. и приведите отступы в коде в положенный вид.

Comment: 1. Ваша функция ничего не возвращает.
2. Вы забыли её вызвать.

Comment: @Hugo предлагаю [изменить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1415386/edit) текст вопроса и добавить туда новую информацию либо изменить её

Comment: изменил, может я не те аргументы указываю в вызове

Comment: еще раз. ваша функция ничего не возвращает, потому что вы ее так написали. Вы вообще непонятно что вызываете в функции.

Comment: tss_packer(cert, key)  всего два аргумента!!! результат будет в файле [ cert.name+'_'+key.name + 'txt' ] вы его нигде не показываете после создания!!!

Answer (score 0):

Функция записывает содержимое двух файлов в новый третий. Я не особо понял, что   она должна возвращать. Сейчас она просто будет выводить в консоль сообщение, если вам надо возвращать какое-то значение, то добавьте `return`

````
from os.path import basename


def tss_patcher(first_PATH: str, second_PATH: str):
    new_filename = f"{basename(first_PATH)}_{basename(second_PATH)}.txt"
    with open(new_filename, "w+", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.writelines(input(first_PATH))
        file.write("\n")
        file.writelines(input(second_PATH))
    print("Файл записан")


tss_patcher(first_PATH="first.txt",
            second_PATH="second.txt")```
````